# Continue sequence of confusing numbers

Tags: sequences-and-series

I have a sequence, need to continue it:
1011, 14, 13, E, 1111...

Well it's obvious that we have several number systems here, my guess (maybe I'm wrong) that 1011 is in binary, 14/13 are decimal, E - hex, then binary again, so in decimal form we have sequence:

11, 14, 13, 14, 15...

So the answer is 16, but it my logic is so primitive, I doubt that I m right.

Comment: base 2, base 8, base 10, base 16

Comment: thanks, I knew that was something really simple, then I have:  
1011, 14, 13, E, 1111, 20  
am I correct?